# Unbuffered output from IHTTPHandler

Tags: c#, .net, ihttphandler

I want to stream data from an `IHttpHandler` class. I'm loading a large number of rows from the DB, serializing, and compressing them, then sending them down the wire. On the other end, I want my client to be able decompress, and deserialize the data before the server is even done serializing all the objects.

I'm using `context.Response.OutputSteam.Write` to write my data, but it still seems like the output data is being put into a buffer before being sent to the client. Is there a way to avoid this buffering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Response.Flush` method should send it down the wire; however, there are some exceptions.  If IIS is using Dynamic Compression, that is it's configured to compress dynamic content, then IIS will not flush the stream.  Then there is the whole 'chunked' transfer encoding.  If you have not specified `Content-Length` then the recieving end does not know how large the response body will be.  This is accomplished with the chunked transfer encoding.  Some HTTP servers require that the client uses an `Accept-Encoding` request header containing the chunked keyword.  Others just default to chunked when you begin writing bytes before the full length is specified; however, they do not do this if you have specified your own `Transfer-Encoding` response header.

With IIS 7 and compression disabled, `Response.Flush` should then always do the trick, right?  Not really.  IIS 7 can have many modules that intercept and interact with the request and response.  I don't know if any that are installed/enabled by default, but you should still be aware that they can effect your desired result.

> ... I'm loading a large number of rows from the DB, serializing, and ***compressing*** them, then sending them down the wire...

Curious that you are compressing this content.  If you are using GZIP then you will not be in control of when and how much data is sent by calling flush.  Additionally using GZIP content means that the receiving end may also be unable to start reading data right away.

You may want to break the records into smaller, digestible chucks of 10, 50, or 100 rows.  Compress that and send it, then work on the next set of rows.  Of course now you will need to write something to the client so they know how big each compressed set of rows is, and when they have reached the end.  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding for an example of how the chunked transfer works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context.Response.Flush()` or `context.Response.OutputSteam.Flush()` to force buffered content to be written immediately.

Comment: But does that really flush the network stream? Or is IIS using a MemoryStream internally, so flushing a MemoryStream really has no effect. 

The ContentType is set in the header. So I should only be able to set that before writing data to the stream, but I see examples all over the place of setting the ContentType after writing to the output stream. So at what point does IIS actually compile the header and start sending the body?