# How to perform a download instantly with ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, httpcontext

We have a rather large amount of data to be downloaded.

Currently our system just outputs the stream (we do not use files)

Code:

```
         HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());

            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

However, it is using an extensive amount of memory on the server, waiting for the file to download.. I'd like to make it so it starts to download immediately rather than waiting... How can I do this?

Comment: this is more-or-less covered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781732/unbuffered-output-from-ihttphandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
```

Comment: You could have added a bit more explanation as to why buffering should be off. Switching buffering off sends data to the client as you write it to the output buffer rather than waiting till the end.

Answer (score 4):

the problem is the `MemoryStream.ToArray` method which puts the whole content in the web server memory.

you should pass the memory stream differently to the `BinaryWrite` so you can profit from buffering and stream down data to the client without requiring too much memory.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than convert the entire download into an Array you should copy the data straight from the source stream to the destination stream.

See [Best way to copy between two Stream instances - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230128/best-way-to-copy-between-two-stream-instances-c) for a good way of copying between streams.

From a guess `ms` is a memory stream, and so the following should do the trick:

```
CopyStream(ms, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
```

Better yet would be to write directly to the output stream rather than to the intermediate stream, however how you do this depends on how you got the data contained in `ms`.